# How to get $row[0] from readList into action function

Tags: php

```
class readData{

  protected $db;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->db = Database::getConnection();
  }

  public function readList($id, $table, $dbName, $action=1){
      if(!$this->db->select_db($dbName)){
        echo "Failed Database";
      }
      $table = $table;
      $id = $id;


      $query = "SELECT * FROM $dbName.$table ORDER BY $id";

      $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
      $result->execute();

      $data= $result->get_result();

      $check = $data->num_rows;

      //count columns
      $no_of_cols = $result->field_count;

      $second = 'Show columns from ' . $table;
      $secondResult = $this->db->prepare($second);
      $secondResult->execute();
      $secondData = $secondResult->get_result();


       if($check > 0){
            echo '<div class="table-responsive">';
            echo '<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">';
            echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';

            while($row = $secondData->fetch_array()):
              echo '<th>'.$row[0].'</th>';
            endwhile;
            if($action == 1){
                echo '<th>actions</th>';
            }

            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
            echo '<tbody>';

            while ($row = $data->fetch_array()):
              echo '<tr>';
              for($i=0;$i<$no_of_cols;$i++){
                echo '<td>'.$row[$i].'</td>';
              }
              if($action == 1){
                $this->action();
              }
              echo '</tr>';

           endwhile;

           echo '</tbody>';
           echo '</table>';
           echo '</div>';
           $result->free_result();
           $secondResult->free_result();
           $this->db->close();
        }
       else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">No records found</div>';
       }
    }

    public function action(){
      // $row = new readData();
      return '<td><a href="update.php?id='.$row[0].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></a><a href="#" data-id='.$row[0].' data-target="#confirm-delete" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>';

    } 

}
```

in view.php

```
  $view = new readData();
    $view -> readList("id", "tableName","dbname", 1);
```

new with OOP and I am trying to learn. 
wanted to set button action for only user page which will allow edit or delete. But if vuew table list only, it wouldnt print buttons. So in view.php, if set action =1, it will print buttons else no buttons.
Is there any way to set $row ?

Comment: `$row[0]` is not available in the scope of your `action()` method. Pass a value to your `action()` method, `$this->action($var)`, and then use this `$var` in your method.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul - i tried with $var inside action() but didn't see it working. Thank you so much. Resolved.